# .net mvc 5 oauth2 server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

i tried to look for how to build oauth authorization server, and found example from [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server)

But I didn't understand the part of code highlighted as yellow in linked picture:

[image: image link here]

1. Why need to check `Response.StatusCode` first ?
2. Where these responses came from ?
3. Is there any better example to implement OAuth2 server that just using this package?

Comment: You are basically asking how the web works... status 200 means Success. And if there is no identity information, we should challenge the user to login.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what i don't really understand is why a response would exit in advance when a request comes into the controller ? hope someone could teach me about that / \